# Receiving file on connection timed out

Tags: java, android, file, server, client

I made a server that sends a text file to the client (Android) and I'm only getting the file when I'm getting connection timed out.

Why the "connection timed out" is happening in the first place? and also, it takes like 1 minute to the file to be received (1MB).

Server:

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                                        new File("123.txt");
                                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

                                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[8192];

                                OutputStream os;
                                try {
                                    os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
                                    int read;

                                    while ((read = dis.read(mybytearray)) > 0) {
                                        dos.write(mybytearray, 0, read);

                                    }

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
```

Client:

```
InputStream in;
                                    int Size = 0;

                                    try {
                                        Size = clientSocket.getReceiveBufferSize();
                                        in = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                                        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);
                                        byte[] buffer = new byte[Size];
                                        int read;

                                        while ((read = dis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                                            fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
                                        }

                                    } catch (IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: Did you search for keywords matching your error message?

Comment: Yes I did, but Alex found an answer. thank you for replying.

Comment: Surely you mean 'read timeout', not 'connection timeout'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't close stream on the server side. So nobody knows that this is the end of stream and wait continues till time out. Add close() like this:

```
 os = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
 DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(os);
 int read;

  while ((read = dis.read(mybytearray)) > 0) {
       dos.write(mybytearray, 0, read);
  }
  os.close();
```

Also, on client side you should expect zero input. Its is OK for slow connection. Only -1 means that connection is closed. Change code like this:

```
while ((read = dis.read(buffer)) > -1)
```

Comment: You should *not* expect zero, on a slow connection or anywhere else. It is impossible for `InputStream.read()` to return zero unless you supply a zero length. See the Javadoc.

Comment: So, when I supply the zero length it is possible. Right? The reason I added  this is because I actually had zero length. Please, remove your negative vote.

Comment: When you supply a zero length it is *certain,* not just 'possible', and it has nothing whatsoever to do with slow links. Why you would want to loop forever on a coding bug is another mystery.